# Need to find control valve for damper

Tags: hvac

There is no control valve attached to this damper:

[image]

so I can't turn it to open/close the duct. It's currently closed :-(. It's smooth so I haven't found anything that can even grasp onto it tightly enough. What kind of part am I looking for or how can i turn it?

Comment: Have you tried Vise Grips? Or, try removing the entire vent using those tempting-looking hex bolts on the frame.

Comment: Or perhaps push/pull on that center rod instead of twisting?

Comment: I have installed similar looking vents and to open you turn the screw clockwise this raises the the 2 1/2 plate dampers. Since the knob is missing you will probably need a pair of pliers. If the screw is rusted in place this is a 2 piece unit the vent and the damper a new damper comes with a knob these are not very expensive and not hard to change. [link to 1 page](http://www.mscdirect.com/browse/tnpla/76941731?src=pla&cid=PLA-Google-PLA+-+Test&CS_003=7867724&CS_010=76941731&mkwid=%5B*GCLIP*%5D&prcid=%5B*GCLSRC%5D).

Comment: The screw seems to be rather stuck. I think your suggestions will lead me in the right direction even if I have to replace the damper. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to easily open the plate dampers with Vise Grip Pliers. The locking mechanism on the Vise Grip is great.

As [Ed Beal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44366/ed-beal) stated in his comment, I think replacing the damper is a good solution because it 1) saves time looking for an obscure part and 2) manual dampers are not too expensive.